# Magento 2: Changing a Block's Template

Tags: layout, blocks, magento2, phtml

In Magento 1, as a module developer it's possible to change a block's template using layout XML code something like this

```
<reference name="block_to_change">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <param>/path/to/template.phtml</param>
    </action>
</reference>
```

and then adding your template to the base theme.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/path/to/template.phtml
```

Is it possible, as a module developer, to do something similar in Magento 2? Or would I need to use layout XML or PHP code to **remove** the block I'm interested in, and insert a new block with a different template (whose class extends the original block class's)

I know I could create a custom theme that replaces a template, but I'm interested in creating a module that changes the default template, but still allows a custom theme to then replace that template.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Of course, it is possible:

```
<referenceBlock name="copyright">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Dfr_Backend::page/copyright.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Can you explain the steps how can i change the layout, Actually i want to update the add to addtocart.phtml file according to system configuration and also want to update this using custom module

Comment: KAndy solution didn't work for me but this one yes

Comment: I have changed the template of the block name "customer_account_dashboard_top"<body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::order/recentorder.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>" but its not getting work, kindly check and let me know your comments

Comment: `action` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 52):

Action node is deprecated, but you can use block arguments

```
<referenceBlock name="block_to_change">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]_[Module]::/path/to/template.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Can you explain the steps how can i change the layout, Actually i want to update the add to `addtocart.phtml` file according to system configuration and also want to update this using custom module

Comment: @KAndy would you mind clarifying where the statement "action node is deprecated is coming from" -  after a quick search of the current core code base I found 4 uses with referenceBlock changing the template . All 4 of them use the action node to set a template and none this approach.

Comment: Thanks - I'll just leave a reference to a bug report here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3356 - the method posted in this answer, while possibly the future way of doing things, does not yet work as advertised

Comment: @KAndy Is your code example 100% correct? I tried that and I can't get it to work in any way. The other answer from @Mage2.PRO (which uses `<action method='setTemplate'>`) works without problems.

Comment: ?It will work for adding custom template phtml file to my custom module where i want to add dynamic drag and drop sortable multiple list for product attributes, let me know if anything else needs to be done here?

Comment: Has this been chnaged? It doesn't seem to be working now.

Comment: This doesn't work. Accepted answer does though.

Comment: @KAndy If i use arguments set template in layout inside module area. But i have same layout file and define template in theme area. Is layout in module will take over higher priority than theme ?

Comment: Do you mean `[Vendor]_[Module]` or `[Themebase]_[Themename]`

Answer (score 37):

To understand the difference between `<arguments>` and `<action>` you must understand how the constructors of Magento 2 objects work. If you override a constructor in Magento, you'll always get a `$data-parameter` which is an array. This is the data as provided in the XML files and translated to the internal `$_data-array` of `\Magento\Framework\DataObject`:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Foo_Bar::buzz.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>    

...

public function __construct(array $data = [])
{
    // $_data is populated with the arguments from XML:
    // so $_data['template'] is now 'Foo_Bar::buzz.phtml'
    $this->_data = $data;
}
```

However, in the case of a template, if `setTemplate()` is used in the pseudo constructor (`_construct()`, single underscore), this means that the `$data` is overridden, no matter if it's set in the XML.

```
public function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('foo/bar.phtml');
}
```

In that scenario, `<action>` is prefered, since this is executed after the constructor & pseudo constructor.

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Foo_Bar::buzz.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 19):

The following worked for me in Magento EE 2.2.3

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="core.module.block.name" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::path/to/your/template.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Note:** if you are using a custom module to change a core's template and you are going mad because the previous code snipped does not work, make sure your module is loaded after the core module you are trying to change (module.xml) and you executed `bin/magento setup:upgrade` :)

Comment: This is the cleanest way in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why, but i find this way to be the best:

```
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers.default" template="Foo_Bar::sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers.default" template="Foo_Bar::sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
```

This will work only if your block wasn't overwritten before using `setTemplate` method. Magento 2.2.x and higher.

Comment: This is exactly the same piece of code as [Aivoris’ answer above](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219241/92968).