# replace or over write the Magento 2 footer phtml file

Tags: magento2, footer

How to replace or overwrite the footer phtml file without changing the core file of Magento 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Changing a Block's Template](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template)

Answer (score 2):

You can use layout mechanism for this.

Create file [VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="version">
       <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::footer.phtml</argument>
       </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

now you can create file [VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/adminhtml/templates/footer.phtml and add you content