# how do overriding Block with template has changed?

Tags: blocks, magento2, overrides, magento2-dev-beta

I want to override the block :

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

This block has template. I want to override this block with a template on a condition. Template is `product/view/addtocart.phtml`.

**Edited**
I tried is success.

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info.addtocart')->setTemplate('Namespace_Modulename::tempalte.phtml');
```

Comment: I don't get it. Do you just want to change the template? 
If yes, it was already answered here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template

Comment: I want set template in Block. because i want check some condition before set template.

Comment: This is probably not the best way. What condition are you testing? Where are you doing `$this->getLayout()->getBlock()...`?

Comment: condition testing is if product out of stock then overrite block and template of block 'product.info.addtocart'. that code i use in custom block override block  'Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View'