# Change block's template in layout XML

Tags: magento2, layout, template, action

How to change block's template in layout XML? I tried the solution proposed in [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86198/14809):

```
<referenceBlock name="copyright">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::new.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

but I can't get it to work. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong.

If I change it to `action method="setTemplate"` (just like in other popular answer for this question, e.g. [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86190/14809)):

```
<referenceBlock name="copyright">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::new.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

all works fine and the template file is correctly changed.

**So what is wrong in the first example?** I'd like to avoid using `action` since it is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

To me, the fist syntax is definitely not right, an issue has even been raised regarding it: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3356

The use of the `setTemplate` action method is still right for now as it has not been refactored yet.

Also as an alternative, you should try:

```
<referenceBlock name="copyright" template="Vendor_Module::new.phtml" />
```

Comment: Can confirm for Magento 2.2 that `<referenceBlock template="..." />` works

Answer (score 2):

You have to set new template file using `default.xml` file,

Set below xml inside your theme default.xml file and remove cache and see changes.

Add new.phtml file inside `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/new.phtml` file

```
 <referenceBlock name="copyright" template="Vendor_Module::new.phtml" />
```