# How to switch off cache in referenceBlock

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to switch off caching in referenceBlock.
I tried:

```
<referenceBlock name="block.name">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="cacheable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

and

```
<referenceBlock name="wp.homepage.view" cacheable="false"/>
```

But none of this is working

Comment: have you working  below code for u?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `cacheable="false"` within `<block>` not `<referenceBlock>`. According to the [README for the core PageCache module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/PageCache/README.md):

> Blocks can also be set as non-cacheable by setting the 'cacheable' attribute in layout XML files.
>
> For example `<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />`. Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

For example:

```
<block class="Package\Module\Block\Test" name="block.name" template="Package_Module::test.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

The **referenceBlock** tag does not support the **cacheable** attribute.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not totally right. The `referenceBlock` does not support `cacheable` as an attribute but the way the OP tries to use it is totally valid.

Comment: can you give me any demo for refereneBlock with cacheable support in magento2? plz if you not know well then not comment plz for cacheble.

Comment: it is possible to change the block template  attribute like this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86198/2380 so it is definitely possible to change the cacheable attribute the same way

Comment: @raphael, I haven't seen any demo which support cacheable for referenceBlock, and above given link, have you any answer then plz post so other users can helpful. Here user having issue so you can add answer if possible, i think its not working

Comment: see the duplicate question the answer is from a developer from the team ;)

Comment: but this is not working for users,after not working they have create post for above both scenario are not working for him, so i have given 3rd method to use cacheable

Comment: I read your answer Im just telling you that your assumption is wrong. The code the OP posted is valid I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere else.