# how to setTemplate for top.search in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template, catalogsearch

How to **setTemplate** in **custom module** for search.

**Spacename/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

    <referenceBlock name="topSearch">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Spacename_Modulename::form.mini.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

just want to change his template file. how to do that?

this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template) not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using the arguments tag

NB: this method seems to be buggy when this post is written: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3356

```
<referenceBlock name="top.search">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::form.mini.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

### Using the attribute

```
<referenceBlock name="top.search" template="Vendor_Module::form.mini.phtml" />
```

### Using the action tag

NB: [this tag is deprecated now.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act)

```
<referenceBlock name="top.search">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::form.mini.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: unfortunately not working for me.  when i add this `<referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>` it working in default.xml but above code is not working.

Comment: @QaisarSatti well that's the right way though. You'll have to debug your layout to find out what your problem is. Could be that the block has been removed/renamed. Or your module is not properly configured

Comment: i update the question with my xml code.

Comment: @QaisarSatti are you sure you have this file: app/code/Spacename/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml ?

Comment: @QaisarSatti did you try with the `<action>` tag instead ?

Comment: this worked but i want it to work with **<arguments>** too.

Comment: @QaisarSatti it's a bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3356

Comment: then i will stick to  `<action>`  thanks..

Comment: @QaisarSatti give a try to the alternative solution using the attribute directly (solution #2)

Comment: that is also not working bro for me..