# Add custom copyright text below existing copyright text in Magento 2 frontend by module

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, magento2.1.6

I have attempted several steps to create a custom block to display custom copyright text below the existing default copyright in the frontend.

In my module root directory (`app/code/Ciptaloka/HelloWorld/`), I have these files added:

- `Block\Page\Footer\Copyright.php` - Block file

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Block\Page\Footer;

  use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
  use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

  class Copyright extends Template
  {
      public function __construct(
          Context $context,
          array $data = []
      ) {
          parent::__construct($context, $data);
      }

      public function getCopyrightTxt()
      {
          return __('All products displayed on this website are manufactured by Ciptaloka.com');
      }
  }
  ```
- `view\frontend\templates\html\copyright.phtml` - Template file

  ```
  <small class="copyright">
      <span><?= $this->getCopyrightTxt(); ?></span>
  </small>
  ```
- `view\frontend\layout\page_footer_copyright.xml` - Layout configuration file

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
          <referenceContainer name="copyright">
              <block
                      name="ciptaloka_helloworld.footer.copyright"
                      class="Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Block\Page\Footer\Copyright"
                      after="-"
                      template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
          </referenceContainer>
      </body>
  </page>
  ```

After creating those files, I tested it, but unfortunately it doesn't get displayed.

I want the frontend copyright footer to change from this:

```
<small class="copyright">
  <span>Copyright © 2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.</span>
</small>
```

to become this:

```
<small class="copyright">
  <span>Copyright © 2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.</span>
</small>
<small class="copyright">
  <span>All products displayed on this website are manufactured by Ciptaloka.com</span>
</small>
```

My question is, can it be established by creating custom block on a custom module? If it can, and my codes got something wrong, can you point me out?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**: My layout now looks like this, other files remain unchanged:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block
                    name="ciptaloka_helloworld.footer.copyright"
                    class="Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Block\Page\Footer\Copyright"
                    after="copyright"
                    template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But the result is not what I expected: my custom copyright is placed above the existing copyright message.

[image: My custom copyright is placed above the existing copyright message]

Comment: I cannot believe that for add a simple link into the copyright footer you have to do such a work!!!

Answer (score 4):

Your close, the reason your template is not rendering is because you're using `<referenceContainer name="copyright">`. There are three issues here:

- `copyright` is a block, not a container. Check `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` line `121`. Change `referenceContainer` to `referenceBlock`.
- If you want your change to apply on all pages you need to rename your layout XML file to be `default.xml`
- Because `copyright` is a block you need to call your block inside it (only containers automatically render child blocks). To do this you'll need to overwrite this template - `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/copyright.phtml` so it looks like so:

```
<small class="copyright">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCopyright() ?></span>
</small>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ciptaloka_helloworld.footer.copyright'); ?>
```

### Alternative method

An alternative method would be to render your template via the `before.body.end` container (for Luma only), as this is a container it will automatically render your template.

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block 
        name="ciptaloka_helloworld.footer.copyright"
        class="Ciptaloka\HelloWorld\Block\Page\Footer\Copyright"
        after="copyright"
        template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Does this mean that we cannot purely make modification from custom module codes alone and we must make changes in Magento vendor to achieve this?

Comment: And I think that my custom layout configuration file (`page_footer_copyright.xml`) is not loaded, how to make it be loaded?

Comment: Nooooo never edit files in vendor, you can create the file in your theme and it will overwrite it or if you're doing it in a module you can set the template to use your own - see [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template) answer for how to do that.

If you want your change to render on every page I think you can rename your layout XML file to be `default.xml` and it will render on every page. I haven't tried this before as I only work in themes not modules.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that "overwrite" statement that you wrote, I get it now. I've changed `referenceContainer` to `referenceBlock` and renamed my layout file to `default.xml` but nothing happened. And the answer link you gave me means to change the template of block but what I want is to extend the existing copyright block with my custom block.

Comment: If you want to add your template after the existing breadcrumbs without altering the existing breadcrumb template you will need to use `<referenceContainer name="footer">` and add `after="breadcrumbs"` to your block. At the moment you have added your template but it isn't being rendered anywhere because you haven't called your template file or set the `reference` to a container. As `footer` is a container it should automatically be rendered now. Also make sure you clear cache after making XML changes.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the new info.

Comment: It finally works. I revert back to `referenceContainer` and change the container name to `before.body.end` to place it in before the end of the body. And I put the block rendering after copyright block by `after="copyright"`, but it got placed above the existing copyright block. I want it got placed below.

Comment: Did you try the `footer` container along with `after="copyright`? This should render it right after the existing copyright message. Because you're using a different parent it may be difficult or even impossible to get it to display right after the existing `copyright` block.

Comment: Yes I've tried it. It got placed in the end inside `div class="footer content"` instead, not after the existing copyright message. Preview: http://imgur.com/a/OM5XH

Comment: Oh shoot, I forgot you're using the Luma theme to. Luma moves it to `before.body.end`. In that case using `referenceContainer name="before.body.end"` alongside `after="copyright` should move it right after the existing `copyright` block. If that doesn't work can you update your code in the question please and I'll take a look. I've updated my answer again to reflect the new change.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question with my current code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

For achieving your task you just need to create a static block for your custom  HTML or text and override copyright template file in your theme

Copy **copyright.phtml** file in your theme

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/copyright.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/copyright.phtml

Now call your static block in copyright.phtml file to add custom text below copyright

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<small class="copyright">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCopyright() ?></span>
</small>

<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without overriding the template file in Magento module vendor?

Comment: @RizkiPratama You should accept an answer to help other developers to find their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change using the admin panel on this route below:

**Content > Design > Configuration > SELECT YOUR THEME > Other Settings > Footer > Copyright.**

[image: Footer Copyright Magento 2]

So you can add your code like that and customize using the CSS below:

```
<span>All products displayed on this website are manufactured by Ciptaloka.com</span>
```

---

```
.copyright span{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:10px 0;
}
```

Comment: As I stated in my title, I want to add it by module, NOT by admin configuration from backend page, so when user install this module, the copyright is extended by my custom copyright message.

Comment: @Rafael Corrêa Gomes, can one insert PHP code to display the year inside "Miscellaneous HTML" text area?

Comment: No, it's not possible