# Can't override recent order template from custom module

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, template, overrides

In customer account dashboard there's a recent orders block, i tried to override it like this:

**app/code/Test/SuccessPage/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
          <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top">
              <action method="setTemplate">
                  <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_SuccessPage::order/recent.phtml</argument>
              </action>
          </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Test/SuccessPage/view/frontend/templates/order/recent.phtml**

```
<h1> Success !! </h1>
```

Unfortunately, it's not working at all

Comment: remove reference container from your `customer_account_index.xml` file

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI not working at all

Comment: may be the parameters you are passing should be passed in single inverted coma [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template)

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI single inverted coma not working too

Answer (score 0):

Update code in your layout file.

**=> Test/SuccessPage/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_SuccessPage::order/recent.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: not working at all

Comment: Did you cleared cache. It's working fine for me.

Comment: yes i already cleared cache, and static content deploy

Comment: I see, I test using SR_Stackexchange.

Comment: so i should make layout.xml inside layout folder?

Comment: Yes, Updated. Someone edited my question.

Comment: I have same issue. It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Code is seems  Ok.
May be you need to depends Module at `app/code/Test/SuccessPage/etc/module.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_SuccessPage" setup_version="2.0.0">
    <!-- add this -->
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>

    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: not working either

Comment: Please share your full module?

Comment: I have same issue. It's not working.