# Can't override template from own module

Tags: magento2, layout, template, overrides, upgrade

It seems to be impossible to override the template **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\renderer\actions\edit.phtml** from your own module e.g. by using layout updates.

(The template shows the edit button near quote items in the cart)

**Preconditions:**

Magento 2.3.5-p2

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create own module (In my case: Company_Configurator)
2. Create Template file: **app\code\Company\Configurator\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\renderer\actions\edit.phtml** and change content.
3. Create layout update file **app\code\Company\Configurator\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml** with following content:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <!--
> /**
>  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
>  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
>  */
> -->
> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
>     <body>
>         <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit">
>             <arguments>
>                 <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_Configurator::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml</argument>
>             </arguments>
>         </referenceBlock>
>     </body>
> </page>
> ```

**Attempt 2:**

I even tried to extend the block class, override it with dependency injection and then set the template:

**app/code/Company/Configurator/etc/frontend/di.xml:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>     <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit"
>                 type="Company\Configurator\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" />
> </config>
> ```

**app\code\Company\Configurator\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit.php**

```
namespace Company\Configurator\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions;

class Edit extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit
{
    protected $_template = 'Company_Configurator::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml';

    function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    ...

}
```

**Expected result:**

Template should get changed to own template.

**Actual result:**

Old template is still loading.

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set template directly on `<referenceBlock>` in layout xml like this:

**app\code\Company\Configurator\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Company_Configurator::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml" />
</body>
</page>
```

Tested on Magento 2.3.5-p2

Another way to achieve this is to use `<action method="setTemplate">` it is deprecated but has been for quite some time now and it's still used by Magento core code at various places.

You can also check this for additional info: [Magento 2: Changing a Block's Template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template)

Comment: I tried both methods, but none of them works.

Comment: What product type do you have in cart? This example is for simple only.

Comment: How do you know that it is only for simple products? The layout file is called `checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml`. We are using a custom product type named `company_configurator`

Comment: Because of `checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit` block name and because you have those for each product type within magento, so `configurable`, `bundle`, `virtual`, `grouped` all exist.

Comment: I see, thank you for the hint. We are using a custom product type though, which is called `company_configurator`

Comment: Can you explain why my second attempt failed (see Attempt #2 in my question)?

Comment: I think it is, because layout updates have precedence and so the template set in the block class is not loaded, because it gets overwritten by the layout update.